# How can I implement a “current picture” indicator in my slideshow navigation using JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I've got a slideshow in my website, which is working fine. Now i do have those links, like, 1,2,3,4,5. If you press 1, you go to image 1 and stuff. But now those links are actually circles, like this:

O O O O O

And if you press them, they get filled with a color.

But those are png files, and when i have an active one, it has to become filled, but when i click another, that one has to become active. But i cant change background-image with css, because it is not a background image. I tried some javascript and jquery but i can't get it to work.

The links are build up like this:

```
<a href="#" rel="5" id="image5" title="dada6"><img src="images/image.png" width="15" height="15" /></a>
```

And when i click them, the image has to be changed, and when i click another, the old one must turn normal again, and the new one has to become active.

I have got something like this

```
 <a href="#" rel="1" id="image1" title="i am freaking fabulous"    onMouseOver="document.image001.src=linkPressed.src" onMouseOut="document.image001.src=link.src" onClick="document.image001.src=linkPressed.src"> <img src="images/Jamartss0.png" width="15" height="15" name="image001" /> </a>
```

Comment: “I tried some javascript and jquery but i can't get it to work.” — What have you got so far?

Comment: What is the question here? There is not a single question mark in your post.

Comment: `$('img').attr('src','images/[image_name].png')` will change it, or use `.prop()` if you have jq 1.6

Comment: "But i cant change background-image"... no, but you can change the image itself, by changing the `src` property.

Comment: I tried something with src, but it has to change back once it is not active, only one link can be active once at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a class to your images, eg. 'button', then you can use something like:

```
$(".button").attr("src", "images/image.png");
$("#image5 img").attr("src", "images/image-with-color.png");
```

to change the src used for the images when a circle is clicked.  The first line resets all of them to the blank one, then the second line changes the current one (in this case image5) to the selected one.

**Update:**

I don't know what you have already, but something like this would be where to put the lines:

```
$(function() {
    $(".button-link").click(function(){
        $(".button").attr("src", "images/image.png");
        $("img", this).attr("src", "images/image-with-color.png");
    });
});
```

and add `class='button-link'` to your `<a>` tags.  This will execute those two lines of code whenever one of the links is clicked.

Comment: Thank you, i will try that. Does this one have to be written in the document ready?

Comment: Not exactly.  I'll add details to answer.

Comment: One more question, how do i get the current image, to change, because you used image5, should i change that in something else, some current image variable or so?

Comment: Update now updated :)  Note that I've changed `$("#image5 img")` to `$("img", this)`.  This will select the image in the link that was clicked.

Comment: That is working fine now, thank you.

I do have another question (again), it is an automatic slideshow, how do i make sure the image changes automatic with the slideshow.

Comment: I don't know what slideshow plugin/library you're using, but it probably has some method of controlling it externally, or specifying external control links.  What library are you using?

Comment: It is actually just a bunch of jquery and some css for the positioning,

Answer (score 1):

### [WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mDujZ/)

Look for the **ID** or **class** name of the element containing your buttons:

```
<parent element>  // <-- FIND OUT THE CLASS OR ID NAME of the PARENT element
    <a></a>
    <a></a>
    ....
</parent element>
```

Let's say it's a DIV with **ID** `#navButtons`

just do:

```
function navB(){
    var navbg = $('#navButtons a img').attr('src');
    $('#navButtons a img').click(function() {
       $('#navButtons a img').attr('src', navbg);
        $(this).attr('src', 'http://dummyimage.com/20x20/cf5/fff&text=+');  // SET REPLACEMENT IMAGE      
    });
}

navB();   // USE THIS CALL TO FUNCTION 'navB' WHENEVER YOU NEED IT IN THE REST OF YOUR SCRIPT!
```